# How to match digit even if it has a whitespace before?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches a number of many lengths but it should not match if it's preceded by "@[". So far this is my regex:

```
^(?!(@\[)$)(\b(((\d{4}[ \-]?){3,4})|(\d{3}[\-|\s]?\d{5}[\-|\s]?\d{7})|\d{7,16})\b)
```

It works only if the matching pattern is at the beginning of the text, if I have a whitespace or any other character before, it doesn't match.

I tried adding \s but it didn't work.

The regex should match the number on:

```
lorem ipsum 4167782396624925 lorem
```

But not:

```
lorem ipsum @[4167782396624925 lorem
```

Comment: Your regex does quite a bit more than just match a number of a specific length - it looks like it's trying to match phone numbers or something similar? You need a negative lookbehind, but perhaps you can simplify the example, so people can address just the problem, instead of having to decipher your complicated regex?

Comment: Yes, I'm matching also phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!@\[)\b\d+
```

The `\b` word boundary prevents it from matching at the second digit after `@[`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ZpPZqC/1)